# flashy images from previous cells using sdwebimage ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I used SDWEBImage library to show images in scrollview under the tableview.

My problem is, images load completely but when I scroll tableview flashy images from previous cells or duplicate images show in Imageview. I programmatically created an imageview like below:

[image]

My code is below:

```
for (NSString *stringurl in [[[Arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sports"]valueForKey:@"image"]) {

            UIImageView *yourImageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,10,40,40)];

            NSURL *urlimg=[NSURL URLWithString:stringurl];

           [yourImageView sd_setImageWithURL:urlimg
                                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] options:indexPath.row ? SDWebImageRefreshCached : 0];
      [cell.arenaimgscroll addSubview:yourImageView];

            x = x + 50;
            if (stringurl==NULL) {
                cell.arenaimgscroll.hidden=YES;
            }
            else{
                cell.arenaimgscroll.hidden=NO;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't add screenshots. Show code.

Comment: programmetically added imageview in this tableviewcell .in this cell i used scrollview to show multiple images in one cell.data passed in webservice.

Comment: You can also use `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell`, refer this [git repository](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/UITableViewWithHorizontalScroll).

Answer (score 0):

**Just a short overview, So you get your answer**

UITableView is highly optimized, and thus only keep On-screen visible rows in memory. Now, All rows Cells are cached in Pool and are reused and not regenerated. Whenever, user scrolls the UITableView, it adds the just-hidden rows in Pool and reuses them for next to be visible rows.

**So, now, coming to your answer**

When you scroll your UITableView, UITableView datasource method gets called again for every indexPath, **thus dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier gives you cached cell, which already have UIImageView added, but
you add UIImageView again to it(SOURCE OF ERROR)**

**Better solution will be** 
to add imageView in interface builder

or

you can check, if imageView already added and then skip the step of adding it again

**UPDATE:**

***NOTE*** : *This solution is not optimized as you are already not reusing image elements, but will resolve your problem.*

Add this script above your for loop, *this is for clearing older images(that got reused) from your scrollview(arenaimgscroll)* :

```
    [cell.arenaimgscroll.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    for (NSString *stringurl in [[[Arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sports"]valueForKey:@"image"]) {
   //YOUR CODE
}
```

Comment: oh, that is for removing the subviews from arenaimgscroll. By this we make  sure that older images that got reused from previous cell are removed from scrollview.

Comment: Sorry, forgot - you are using Objective C and not Swift! Updating my answer.